# How to save model in tensorflow federated

Tags: tensorflow-federated

How to save the model in the blow code

if you want to run the code, please visit https://github.com/tensorflow/federated
and download federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb.

I will appreciate it if you told me how to save the model of federated learning in tutorials federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow_federated as tff
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import six
import numpy as np
from six.moves import range
import warnings
import collections
import nest_asyncio
import h5py_character
from tensorflow.keras import layers
nest_asyncio.apply()
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()
np.random.seed(0)


NUM_CLIENTS = 1
NUM_EPOCHS = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 20
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 500
num_classes = 3755

if six.PY3:
    tff.framework.set_default_executor(
        tff.framework.create_local_executor(NUM_CLIENTS))  


data_train = h5py_character.load_characters_data()

print(len(data_train.client_ids))

example_dataset = data_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
    data_train.client_ids[0])


def preprocess(dataset):
    def element_fn(element):
        # element['data'] = tf.expand_dims(element['data'], axis=-1)
        return collections.OrderedDict([
            # ('x', tf.reshape(element['data'], [-1])),
            ('x', tf.reshape(element['data'], [64, 64, 1])),
            ('y', tf.reshape(element['label'], [1])),
        ])

    return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).map(element_fn).shuffle(
        SHUFFLE_BUFFER).batch(BATCH_SIZE)


preprocessed_example_dataset = preprocess(example_dataset)  
print(iter(preprocessed_example_dataset).next())


sample_batch = tf.nest.map_structure(
    lambda x: x.numpy(), iter(preprocessed_example_dataset).next())



def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
    return [preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x))
            for x in client_ids]


sample_clients = data_train.client_ids[0:NUM_CLIENTS]

federated_train_data = make_federated_data(data_train, sample_clients)




def create_compiled_keras_model():

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(64, 64, 1), filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                      padding='same', activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
        layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
        layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'),

        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(3755, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        # metrics=['accuracy'])
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])



    return model


def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
    global model_to_save
    model_to_save = keras_model
    print(keras_model.summary())
    return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)


iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)


state = iterative_process.initialize()

state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)

print('round  1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))

for round_num in range(2, 110):
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
    print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly, we will be using the object [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/checkpoint_manager.py#L26), and its `save_checkpoint`/`load_checkpoint` methods. In particular, you can instantiate a `FileCheckpointManager`, and ask it to save `state` (almost) directly.

`state` in your example is an instance of `tff.python.common_libs.anonymous_tuple.AnonymousTuple` (IIRC), which is not compatible with `tf.convert_to_tensor`, as is needed by `save_checkpoint` and declared in its docstring. The general solution often used in TFF research code is to introduce a Python `attr`s class to convert away from the anonymous tuple as soon as state is returned--see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/flars/flars_fedavg.py#L54) for an example.

Assuming the above, the following sketch should work:

```
# state assumed an anonymous tuple, previously created
# N some integer 

ckpt_manager = FileCheckpointManager(...)
ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(ServerState.from_anon_tuple(state), round_num=N)
```

And to restore from this checkpoint, at any time you can call:

```
state = iterative_process.initialize()
ckpt_manager = FileCheckpointManager(...)
restored_state = ckpt_manager.load_latest_checkpoint(
    ServerState.from_anon_tuple(state))
```

One thing to note: the code pointers linked above are generally in `tff.python.research...`, which is not included in the pip package; so the preferred way to get at them is to either fork the code into your own project, or pull down the repo and build it from source.

Thanks for your interest in TFF!

Comment: ckpt_manager = FileCheckpointManager("…")
state = iterative_process.initialize()
restored_state, round_num = ckpt_manager.load_latest_checkpoint(
ServerState.from_anon_tuple(state))

restored_state, metrics = iterative_process.next(
restored_state, federated_train_data)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, when I try to load the model, I get the following error, I want to know how to deal with this problem.
```python

TypeError: LambdaExecutor asked to create call with incompatible type specifications. Function takes an argument of type <model=<trainable=<dense/kernel=float32[11,2],dense/bias=float32[2]>,non_trainable=<>>,optimizer_state=<int64>,delta_aggregate_state=<>,model_broadcast_state=<>>, but was supplied an argument of type <model=<trainable=<dense/kernel=float32[11,2],dense/bias=float32[2]>,non_trainable=<>>,optimizer_state=<int64>>
```

Comment: This indicates a mismatch between the `ServerState` loaded into and the federated computation generated by the iterative process. If you are using `build_federated_averaging_process`, you'll need to adjust your `ServerState` class to hold attributes of `delta_aggregate_state` and `model_broadcast_state`; these can simply default to empty tuples. This is due to the strongly-typed nature of TFF, and the type encoded [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/b1c2ab5a7892b8e4ffdb8307d3c4bc76f10a3822/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py#L356)

Comment: This is definitely a rough edge in TFF right now; I don't think this symbol is exported, but you should be looking to use a ServerState which is an (attrs class version of) [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/b1c2ab5a7892b8e4ffdb8307d3c4bc76f10a3822/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py#L138)

Comment: Can you tell me please, When testing this code, I find  `NameError: name 'ServerState' is not defined` I see this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/flars/flars_fedavg.py#L54) but I don't know how use it? I must clone this github repo locally and run my script in the root directory of the repo ? or how ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `FileCheckpointManager` in

https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/checkpoint_manager.py

However, this class is not supported by released version (v0.18.0) of TFF. You should copy this file to your project directory, so that you can import `FileCheckpointManager`.

```py
'''
# PASTE YOUR CODE BEFORE HERE

# Required:
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)
state = iterative_process.initialize()
'''

from checkpoint_manager import FileCheckpointManager

fcm = FileCheckpointManager('checkpoint/')

# Save model

round_num = 110 # It depends on rounds you have trained
fcm.save_checkpoint(state, round_num)

# Load model

state, round_num = fcm.load_latest_checkpoint(state)
state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't model.save_weights apply to this problem? I understand that the FileCheckpointManager would do a more complete job (capturing weights per round) but I guess as far as the final federated averaged model is concerned the parameter space should be available in save_weights.