# Saving a tensorflow federated model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I have a tensorflow federated model  as seen below:

```
state = iterative_process.initialize()
```

where state is the state of the server encapsulating the model.

Printing it we have:

```
ServerState(model=ModelWeights(trainable=[array([[ 0.01307054,  0.05205479,  0.16566667, ...,
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)]), ..., ('zeroed_count_agg', ())]), model_broadcast_state=())
```

which is the server state.
I can access the model's parameters with:

```
state.model.trainable
```

which is a list.
What i would like to do is save this and reload it in the future.
Ideally i would like to update a future state of the process (each federated iteration returns a new state) with this model.
Any ideas?

P.S. i also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785825/how-to-save-model-in-tensorflow-federated) SO thread but everything there seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround to this. Create an identical keras model.

```
seq = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
     ...
  ])
```

set the weights of the state to this model and then save the keras model:

```
seq.set_weights(state.model.trainable)
seq.save('...')
```